# Unknown column 'username' in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Been trying to solve this for 2 days now.

When I try to seed user data to my database, I get:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'username' in
>   'field      list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `username`,
>   `password`, `email`,      `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (tony,
>   tony_admin, $2y$10$lBDvjtEu.tYueU
>   AuRutTteHLmOntXSBAZsX.tO.ZK3RtxwiLXOBGW, tony_admin@laravel.com,
>   2018-02-18      00:12:39, 2018-02-18 00:12:39))

User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Create users migration file

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Register controller

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Database seeders

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->command->info("Users table seeded :)");
        Model::reguard();
    }
}

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        User::create(array(
            'name' => 'tony',
            'username' => 'tony_admin',
            'password' => Hash::make('admin'),
            'email' => 'tony_admin@laravel.com'
        ));
    }
}
```

I've tried searching for answers, but all the similar questions seem to trying to use foreign keys, whereas I'm just trying to add a `username` field to the default user class.

I'm using Laravel version 5.5.34. What's going on here?

Comment: Can you make sure that your table actually has the new column `username` by using `DESCRIBE <table>`.

Comment: Your code looks correct, as @Julianv.dBerkmortel suggests, can you post the results of `DESCRIBE`?

Comment: @Julianv.dBerkmortel No, all the columns except `username` have been added, but I believe I put `username` in all the necessary laravel files.

Comment: Did you add the `username` column to the existing migration file that does a `CREATE TABLE` or have you created a new migration file that does an `ALTER TABLE` to add the column?

Comment: @Julianv.dBerkmortel I added it to the existing `CREATE TABLE` migration file, I don't need to create a second migration file for this, do I?

Comment: Yes, you do. A migration runs once, and migration files represent a history of changes to your database. They exist to allow collaborative development, each migration is ran **once** by each developer. This means any time you wish to change your database you must create a new migration.

Comment: @sam Oh, wow. That sounds like a good way to end up with a mess of migration files. Obviously, I'm new to Laravel.

Comment: There are also a lot of ways to end up with a mess when you use Git the wrong way but it's also an incredible tool if you use it correctly. Migration files are kinda the same thing if you ask me.

Comment: You can certainly consolidate your schema into a single migration when you're ready to move from development to release if that's preferable, there's flexibility to follow whatever process is best for you, but during development you'd usually want to keep your migrations as they are because it goes hand in hand with version control for your application, otherwise your database schema would not match what your application expects when reverting commits, or switching branches.

Comment: @MattD Better to have lots of migration files than a SQL error, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People keep answering this with wrong answers so I'm going to post the answer that I got in the comments which worked. I was trying to add the `username` column with the same migration file which had already ran. I needed to create a new migration file to update the `users` table and add the `username`column. Migration files can only be run once in laravel.

Comment: Just a note on "Migration files can only be run once in laravel." - if you're in development, you can undo the migration. This can help when you're working on a feature to keep the number of migration files down. Once *others* may have executed a migration (you've pushed it up to a shared repo, or published it in a public project) you'd want to keep it that way.

Answer (score -1):

Run this all in CMD

```
php artisan view:clear

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan debugbar:clear

composer dump-autoload

php artisan log:clear
```

Comment: None of these will fix OP's issue.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can use this :

```
    DB::table('users')
    ->insert([
        'name' => 'tony',
        'username' => 'tony_admin',
        'password' => Hash::make('admin'),
        'email' => 'tony_admin@laravel.com'
    ]);
```