# Laravel tries to seed column that is not asked for

Tags: php, laravel, seeding, laravel-seeding

I have a strange problem and an hour of googling and searching through stackoverflow didn't get me any closer to a solution. What happens is that when I trye to seed a table (let's call it `my_table` for security purposes) the seeder seems to try to populate columns that I never asked to be seeded.

So, first I run `php artisan migrate` to create my table using the following migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateMyTableTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user');

            $table->tinyInteger('from_default')->nullable(false)->default(7);
            $table->tinyInteger('to_default')->nullable(false)->default(20);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unique('user_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropUnique(['user_id']);
            $table->dropForeign(['user_id']);
        });
    }
}
```

This works well, and when I do `DESCRIBE my_table` I get the following:

```
Field           Type                Null    Key     Default     Extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id              int(10) unsigned    NO      PRI                 auto_increment
user_id         int(10) unsigned    NO      UNI     
from_default    tinyint(4)          NO              7
to_default      tinyint(4)          NO              20
created_at      timestamp           YES
updated_at      timestamp           YES
```

So you can see that the table is created with the exact fields that I want in my migration file. So, now I want to seed this table using the following seed:

```
<?php

use App\DomainLogic\Models\MyTable;
use App\DomainLogic\Models\User;
use Faker\Factory as FakerFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class MyTableTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * @var array list of MyTable Users
     */
    private $myTableUsers = [];

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->createMyTableUsers();
        $myTableUsers = $this->getMyTableUsers();
        foreach ($myTableUsers as $myTableUser) {
            factory(MyTable::class)->create([
                'user_id' => $myTableUser->getKey(),
                'from_default' => 7,
                'to_default' => 20,
            ]);
        }
    }

    private function getMyTableUsers(): array
    {
        return $this->myTableUsers;
    }

    private function createMyTableUsers()
    {
        $faker = FakerFactory::create();

        // My table
        $this->myTableUsers[] = factory(User::class)->create([
            'id' => 2,
            'first_name' => 'Kalle',
            'last_name' => 'Andersson',
            'email' => 'kalle.andersson@email.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password', ['rounds' => 4]),
            'mobile_number' => $faker->e164PhoneNumber,
        ]);
        $this->myTableUsers[] = factory(User::class)->create([
            'id' => 3,
            'first_name' => 'Johan',
            'last_name' => 'Petterson',
            'email' => 'johan.petterson@email.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password', ['rounds' => 4]),
            'mobile_number' => $faker->e164PhoneNumber,
        ]);
        $this->myTableUsers[] = factory(User::class)->create([
            'id' => 4,
            'first_name' => 'Krister',
            'last_name' => 'Johansson',
            'email' => 'krister.johansson@email.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password', ['rounds' => 4]),
            'mobile_number' => $faker->e164PhoneNumber,
        ]);
        $this->myTableUsers[] = factory(User::class)->create([
            'id' => 5,
            'first_name' => 'Daniel',
            'last_name' => 'Eriksson',
            'email' => 'daniel.eriksson@email.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password', ['rounds' => 4]),
            'mobile_number' => $faker->e164PhoneNumber,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When running `php artisan db:seed` I get this error:

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'starts_day_default' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `my_table` (`user_id`, `starts_day_default`, `ends_day_default`, `from_default`, `to_default`) values (2, 07, 20, 7, 20))

In PDOConnection.php line 82:

  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'starts_day_default' in 'field list'

In PDOConnection.php line 80:

  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'starts_day_default' in 'field list'
```

So the strange thing is that as far as I see, I never try to populate a column called `starts_day_default` or `ends_day_default`. Because those columns don't exist and should not exist. The actual thing is that the columns were renamed `starts_day_default -> from_default` and `ends _day_default -> to_default`. The users are created correctly, I can see them in the users table, so that is not the problem. Here is also my model for MyTable:

```
<?php

namespace App\DomainLogic\Models;

use DateTimeImmutable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyTable extends Model
{
    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'my_table';

    /**
     * Creates personal trainer, if personal trainer with id exists.
     *
     * @param int $myTableId
     *
     * @return null|self
     */
    public static function createFromId(int $myTableId): ?self
    {
        $myTable = self::select('my_table.*')
            ->join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'my_table.user_id')
            ->where('my_table.id', '=', $myTableId)
            ->whereNull('user.anonymized_at')
            ->get()
            ->first();

        return $myTable;
    }

    /**
     * Create personal trainer, if user_id exists.
     *
     * @param int $userId
     *
     * @return null|MyTable
     */
    public static function createFromUserId(int $userId): ?self
    {
        return self::where('user_id', $userId)->get()->first();
    }

    /**
     * Gets all personal trainers.
     *
     * @param bool $active
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public static function getMyTables(bool $active = null): Collection
    {
        $query = self::select('my_table.*')
            ->join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'my_table.user_id')
            ->whereNull('user.anonymized_at');

        if (isset($active)) {
            $query->where('user.active', '=', $active);
        }

        $myTables = $query->get();

        return $myTables;
    }

    /**
     * Gets user.
     */
    public function getUser(): User
    {
        $user = $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id')->getResults();

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Check if personal trainers ids are valid.
     *
     * @param array $myTableIds
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function areMyTableIdsValid(array $myTableIds): bool
    {
        $dbMyTableIds = self::select('my_table.id')
            ->join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'my_table.user_id')
            ->whereIn('my_table.id', $myTableIds)
            ->whereNull('user.anonymized_at')
            ->get()
            ->pluck('id')
            ->toArray();

        $dbMyTableIds = array_map('intval', $dbMyTableIds);
        sort($myTableIds);
        sort($dbMyTableIds);

        $result = false;
        if ($myTableIds === $dbMyTableIds) {
            $result = true;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I have tried

```
php artisan view:clear

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan debugbar:clear

composer dump-autoload
```

suggested in [Unknown column 'username' in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847321/unknown-column-username-in-laravel) but that did not help. I have dropped all tables and rerun `php artisan migrate` but that did not help either.

I have never seen this before, so my question is, can anyone see what my problem is?

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

Comment: @MattJameson yes I did try that. I found the solution finally, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved it, I missed that there was a factory file `MyTableFactory` that still contained the faulty columns. The file was very hidden.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the file was in database/factories. I suggest anyone having the same issue to search for all files having `Factory` in it's name and then `Ctrl+F` the column that's causing the issue in each of these found files.